# same String values in PHP are not equal?

Tags: php

I am comparing two same string values in PHP but the result says they are not equal. here is the code

```
 $s = $fname;
 $t = $temp->get_teacher_name()." ";
 echo "<br/> s = $s<br/>";
 echo "<br/> t  = ".$temp->get_teacher_name()."<br/>";

 echo var_dump($s)."<br/>;

 echo var_dump($t);
 if($s == $t)
 {
 echo"<br/>Matching<br/>";
 }
```

The $fname is read from a file using "fgets" and i think it has a extra space at end because of that. 
Here is the result.

[image]

The result says they are not equals.

Comment: Instead of adding a space to the end of `$t`, try running both `$s` and `$t` through `trim()` before you compare them.

Comment: your output with `t=` doesn't actually output what `t` equals. So you're not really showing yourself that the two strings are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use trim() to remove whitespace from beginning and end of string.

```
$s = trim($fname);
$t = trim($temp->get_teacher_name());

if ($s == $t) {
    echo "<br/>Matching<br/>"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working now. but i dont know why it did not work before when they were equal too.

Comment: I can't tell what's going on in $temp->get_teacher_name(). trim() is better then what you tried to do. Accept the answer if it helped you ;)